# Android java.lang.nullpointerexception with printwriter

Tags: java, android, sockets

So I am getting a null pointer exception with my code. The line causing the error is the third from last. The error is that the out is null. What I do not know is why the out remains null after having been declared. I am a c++ programmer learning java to write android apps with.

```
public class Connection implements Runnable
{
    private static String temp_ip="127.0.0.1";
    //temp_ip="74.125.225.179";
    private Socket sock;
    private static final int Port=80;
    private static final String IP = temp_ip;
    public double lat;
    public double longi;
    public double accuracy;
    private String message;
    public Location location;
    private PrintWriter out;
    private boolean running=false;
    Thread thread=null;

public void start()
{
    if (thread ==null)
    {
        set_run(true);
        try {thread=new Thread(this);}
        catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
        try {thread.start();}
        catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
    }
}
public void run()
{
    init_ports();
    init_connect();
}
public void set_run(boolean a)
{
    running=a;
}

private void init_connect()
{
    Log.v(null, "init_connect called");
    try
    {
        out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(sock.getOutputStream())),true);
    }
    catch (UnknownHostException e)
    {e.printStackTrace();}
    catch (IOException e)
    {e.printStackTrace();}
    catch (Exception e)
    {e.printStackTrace();}}
private void init_ports()
{
    Log.v(null, "init_ports called");
    try
    {
        InetAddress addr= InetAddress.getByName(IP);
        sock= new Socket(addr,Port);
    }
    catch (UnknownHostException e)
    {e.printStackTrace();}
    catch (IOException e)
    {e.printStackTrace();}
}
public void wardit()
{
    lat= location.getLatitude();
    longi= location.getLongitude();
    accuracy= location.getAccuracy();
    message= String.valueOf(lat)+"$"+String.valueOf(longi)+"$"+String.valueOf(accuracy);
    out.println(message);
    Log.v(null, "wardit called");
}
```

}

Comment: You initialize out in a try block, that doesn't necessarily mean it is initialized when you use it. Where is wardit called? You should use camelcase for your methods

Comment: Ok, so how would you go about initializing it? What am I missing from where its initialized vs being used?

Comment: well, you ought to check that your object is not null before you use it. if it is null you should display some error message for the user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please provide code, from which you're calling `wardit()` method?

You're probably doing something like this:

```
Connection conn = new Connection;
Connection.start();
Connection.wardit();
```

This approach will lead to null pointer exception: Connection is doing init's in other thread and `out`, that you call in `wardit()` method is not initialized.
You should try smth like that(it's dumb a little, better approach is to use java.util.concurrent Locks instead):

```
public class Connection implements Runnable
{
    private static String temp_ip="127.0.0.1";
    //temp_ip="74.125.225.179";
    private Socket sock;
    private static final int Port=80;
    private static final String IP = temp_ip;
    public double lat;
    public double longi;
    public double accuracy;
    private String message;
    public Location location;
    private PrintWriter out;
    private boolean running=false;
    Thread thread=null;

public void start()
{
    if (thread ==null)
    {
        set_run(true);
        try {thread=new Thread(this);}
        catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
        try {thread.start();}
        catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
    }
}
public void run()
{
    try{
        init_ports();
        init_connect();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public void set_run(boolean a)
{
    running=a;
}

private void synchronized init_connect() throws InterruptedException
{
    Log.v(null, "init_connect called");
    try
    {
        out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(sock.getOutputStream())),true);
        notifyAll();
    }
    catch (UnknownHostException e)
    {e.printStackTrace();}
    catch (IOException e)
    {e.printStackTrace();}
    catch (Exception e)
    {e.printStackTrace();}}
private void init_ports()
{
    Log.v(null, "init_ports called");
    try
    {
        InetAddress addr= InetAddress.getByName(IP);
        sock= new Socket(addr,Port);
    }
    catch (UnknownHostException e)
    {e.printStackTrace();}
    catch (IOException e)
    {e.printStackTrace();}
}
public void synchronized wardit() throws InterruptedException
{
    lat= location.getLatitude();
    longi= location.getLongitude();
    accuracy= location.getAccuracy();
    message= String.valueOf(lat)+"$"+String.valueOf(longi)+"$"+String.valueOf(accuracy);
    while(out==null){
        wait();
    }
    out.println(message);
    Log.v(null, "wardit called");
}
```

this will make thread to wail untill out is set:
`wait()` will make thread, trying to access `out` wait for "not null" value. It will wait until `notify()` in `init_connect()` is called (it's called after `out` is set).

Edit in code: you should use `notifyAll()` instead of `notify()` in case you got more than one thread trying to call `wardit()`

Comment: You guessed correctly how I am calling it. I added in all your changes but out is still null and now it hands forever waiting for out to initialize. Any ideas would help alot :)

Comment: That can mean only one thing: out is never initialized. Can you check in log is init_connection even called? Are there any exceptions' stacktraces in console?

Comment: The other thing to check: is there socket open on 127.0.0.1:80?

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comment, you initialize `out` in a try block. If you say that it is null and it throws a NPE, then it's clear that it hasn't been initialized before. Do you call init_connect before calling wardit? If so, creating the PrintWriter must fail